# How much energy is required by a planet like Earth to support and maintain life as we know it?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, visible-light, cosmology

How much energy is required by a planet like Earth to support and maintain life as we know it and could this energy be provided by a star the size of the moon, located where the moon is without compromising life on Earth itself?

Comment: An object the size of the moon cannot be a star. It does not have enough mass to compress hydrogen into fusion.

Comment: If it emits 6000K blackbody radiation, sure.

Comment: Is this just about energy, or do things like the specific absorbtion wavelengths of chlorophyll come into play? The Moon has 29′20″ – 34′6″ angular diameter, and can thus appear smaller or bigger than the sun (31′27″ – 32′32″) - To match energies while retaining a blackbody spectrum, it would need to sometimes be colder, sometimes hotter than the sun, playing havoc with the crucial  blue/red ratio needed for photosynthesis.

Comment: This sort of question is better suited to Worldbuilding SE.

Answer (score 3):

Let's initially ignore the fact that the Moon can't be a star unless it is much heavier than the Moon and the whole idea is not plausible in many other ways: see the end of the answer for more on this.

One question to ask is, If the Moon *was* a star, how hot it would need to be: if it was too hot then it will be too blue and there will be too much short-wavelength radiation from it which will mean life can't exist as things get ionized.

Now it is in fact immediately obvious from the fact that the Moon and the Sun are approximately the same size in the sky that the surface temperature of the star-Moon will be the same as the Sun's if it delivers the same power to Earth and we're going to be OK, but we can check that.

First of all we know the amount of power arriving at the top of the atmosphere from the Sun and we know this is enough to drive life on Earth.  So that's the amount of power we need (and we can get away with somewhat less or somewhat more, but that's a question of climate which I don't want to get involved in here).  The TOA flux from the Sun (at the point directly under the Sun) is about

$$f=1360\,\mathrm{Wm^{-2}}$$.

A little bit of thinking about geometry gives a figure for the flux, $F$, at the star-Moon's surface which is needed to give this flux at the surface of the Earth.  This number is

$$F = \frac{R_M^2}{(R_O - R_E)^2}f$$

Where

- $R_M \approx 1.7\times 10^6\,\mathrm{m}$ is the radius of the star-Moon, assumed to be the same as the radius of the Moon;
- $R_E \approx 6.4\times 10^6\,\mathrm{m}$ is the radius of the Earth;
- $R_O \approx 3.8\times 10^8\,\mathrm{m}$ is the orbital radius of the star-Moon.

(You need $R_O - R_E$ because the orbital radius is measured from the centre of the Earth while the flux is at the surface: it's not a big correction though.)

So this gives a figure for $F$:

$$F \approx 6.4\times 10^7\,\mathrm{Wm^{-2}}$$

This is the flux at the surface of the star-Moon.  We now use $F = \sigma T^4$ to work out the temperature of the surface of the star-Moon, assuming it's a black-body which will be a good assumption.  And you get

$$T \approx 5800\,\mathrm{K}$$

And conveniently this is close to the surface temperature of the Sun.

So, if you could make a star the size and mass of the Moon, then if it produced enough energy to keep life on Earth going, then it would be about the right temperature.

---

The other question to ask is: are there plausible types of star which might be about the size of the Moon and have a reasonable temperature?  I think the answer is no, there are not, with the disclaimer that I am not an astrophysicist: anything the size of the moon is either hostile in terms of radiation or in terms of mass.

The three possible candidates (I think) are white dwarfs, neutron stars and black holes.  We can rule out the second two as they're not going to provide environments friendly to life: they may essentially not radiate at all, but if they do they tend to spit out a lot of X-rays and other nasty stuff which is going to sterilise planets near them.

So what about [white dwarfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_dwarf)?  There's an immediate problem with such an object in that it has no source of fuel left so it gradually cools.  But white dwarfs can remain at reasonable temperatures for several billion years, which is perhaps long enough for life to evolve.

But there is another problem: white dwarfs have a surprising relationship between mass and radius: small ones are more massive.  Additionally there's an upper limit to their mass, which is about $1.4M_\odot$ (this is called the Chandrasekhar limit).  I don't know if a white dwarf with a radius the same as the Moon is possible at all, but if it is it is going to have a mass of more than the Sun, and it's going to be alarmingly close to the Chandrasekhar limit.  But perhaps such a thing could exist, and if it could it could probably sit at a reasonable temperature for long enough.

But unfortunately orbital mechanics gets you: this thing would not be orbiting the Earth, the Earth would be orbiting it.  And the period of the orbit is given by

$$P = 2\pi \sqrt{\frac{R_O^3}{G M}}$$

where $R_O$ is the same $R_O$ as above, and I'll take $M = M_\odot$.  Well, you can plug in the numbers, and you get $P\approx 4400\,\mathrm{s}$: a little over an hour.  With a period like that the Earth would, I'm sure, be tidally locked, and so would not have a recognisably Earth-like climate.  In fact I have a strong suspicion that the Earth would be inside its Roche limit, and would therefore not exist other than as a possible ring system.

So, no, none of this works.

Comment: See also: "[Calculating the Radius of a Star](http://cas.sdss.org/dr4/en/proj/advanced/hr/radius1.asp)" and remember to remain on a line from the [HR diagram](https://www.atnf.csiro.au/outreach/education/senior/astrophysics/stellarevolution_hrintro.html).

Answer (score 1):

> How much energy is required by a planet like Earth to support and maintain life as we know it ?

A star approximately the size of our Sun, situated approximately the same distance away.

> ... and could this energy be provided by a star the size of the moon, located where the moon is without compromising life on Earth itself?

No.

By "definition" (not mathematically supported) the smallest "star" is 13 times the size of Jupiter. Mathematically a "*star*" could be slightly larger than Jupiter, but such an object would be quite cool.

Stars can only have a particular range of masses and as a result have a temperature, our Sun's temperature (color) is 5,778 K (while the actual temperature of the outermost region of [the sun's atmosphere is at millions of degrees](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/i-read-that-the-suns-surf/)).

What makes the color ([Planckian locus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planckian_locus)) more important than the actual temperature is that plants require light wavelengths within the [action spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosynthetically_active_radiation). The thermal radiation spontaneously emitted by an object can be approximated as [black-body radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation). The get a particular spectrum of light an object must be a specific size (mass/radius ratio is explained below), that size is **not the size of the moon**.

[image: The color (chromaticity) of black-body radiation depends on the temperature of the black body.]

The [temperature relation between a planet and its star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation#Temperature_relation_between_a_planet_and_its_star) is easily calculated:

> "The actual temperature of the planet will likely be different, depending on its surface and atmospheric properties. Ignoring the atmosphere and greenhouse effect, the planet, since it is at a much lower temperature than the Sun, emits mostly in the infrared (IR) portion of the spectrum. In this frequency range, it emits $\overline{\epsilon}$ of the radiation that a black body would emit where $\overline{\epsilon}$ is the average emissivity in the IR range. The power emitted by the planet is then:
>
> $$P_{\rm emt} = \overline{\epsilon}\,P_{\rm emt\,bb} \qquad \qquad \qquad (5)$$
>
> For a body in radiative exchange equilibrium with its surroundings, the rate at which it emits radiant energy is equal to the rate at which it absorbs it:
>
> $$P_{\rm abs}=P_{\rm emt} \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad (6)$$
>
> Substituting the expressions for solar and planet power in equations 1–6 and simplifying yields the estimated temperature of the planet, ignoring greenhouse effect, $T_P$:
>
> $$T_{P}=T_{S}{\sqrt {{\frac {R_{S}{\sqrt {{\frac {1-\alpha }{\overline {\varepsilon }}}}}}{2D}}}}\qquad \qquad (7)$$
>
> In other words, given the assumptions made, the temperature of a planet depends only on the surface temperature of the Sun, the radius of the Sun, the distance between the planet and the Sun, the albedo and the IR emissivity of the planet.
>
> Notice that a gray (flat spectrum) ball where $({1-\alpha })={\overline {\varepsilon }}$ comes to the same temperature as a black body no matter how dark or light gray.
>
> **Effective temperature of Earth**
>
> Substituting the measured values for the Sun and Earth yields:
>
> $ T_{\rm S} = 5778 \ \mathrm{K},$
>
> $ R_{\rm S} = 6.96 \times 10^8 \ \mathrm{m},$
>
> $ D = 1.496 \times 10^{11} \ \mathrm{m},$
>
> $ \alpha = 0.306 \ $
>
> With the average emissivity $\overline {\varepsilon }$ set to unity, the effective temperature of the Earth is:
>
> $T_{\rm E} = 254.356\ \mathrm{K}$
>
> or −18.8 °C.
>
> This is the temperature of the Earth if it radiated as a perfect black body in the infrared, assuming an unchanging albedo and ignoring greenhouse effects (which can raise the surface temperature of a body above what it would be if it were a perfect black body in all spectrums). The Earth in fact radiates not quite as a perfect black body in the infrared which will raise the estimated temperature a few degrees above the effective temperature.".

See: "[Stellar Diameters and Temperatures II. Main Sequence K & M Stars](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.2431)" (Aug 20 2012), by Tabetha S. Boyajian, Kaspar von Braun, Gerard van Belle, Harold A. McAlister, Theo A. ten Brummelaar, Stephen R. Kane, Phil Muirhead, Jeremy Jones, Russel White, Gail Schaefer, David Ciardi, Todd Henry, Mercedes López-Morales, Stephen Ridgway, Douglas Gies, Wei-Chun Jao, Bárbara Rojas-Ayala, J. Robert Parks, Laszlo Sturmann, Judit Sturmann, Nils H. Turner, Chris Farrington, P. J. Goldfinger, and David H. Berger.

[image: Temperature vs. Radius]

> "Fig. 13.— Temperature-radius relation is shown as a solid black line (Equation 8) for the approximate range that the relation holds true. The relation including the Sun (Equation 9) is shown as a blue line, where the dotted line is an extrapolation of the curve to higher temperatures with the Sun as a reference point. The color of the data point reflects the
> metallicity of the star. Errors are not plotted, but are typically of the sizes of the data points. The left-most orange dot is the Sun. Solar metallicity Dartmouth models are used to plot the positions at 1 Gyr for stars with masses of 1.0 M$_\odot$, 0.9M$_\odot$, and 0.8M$_\odot$ (black ×, red +, and blue ∗ respectively). Arrows point to their positions at an age of 4.5 Gyr. See Section 5.3 for details.".

[image: Mass vs. Radius]

> "Fig. 15.— Mass-radius relations for single and binary stars as expressed in Equations 10 and 11. The filled circles and solid line are the data and solution for single stars. The open squares and dotted line are for the EB stars. The measured 1-sigma errors are shown for radii, but are typically smaller than the data point. Single star mass errors are not shown for clarity. We show a typical single star mass error bar for a given mass at the bottom of the plot window indicating a value of σMSS ∼ 10 %. Although the mass errors for single stars are large, we do not detect any metallicity dependence on the mass-radius relation. See Section 5.4 for details.".
>
> **[Current IAU standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_dwarf#Current_IAU_standard)**
>
> Currently, the International Astronomical Union considers an object above 13 MJ (the limiting mass for thermonuclear fusion of deuterium) to be a brown dwarf, whereas an object under that mass (and orbiting a star or stellar remnant) is considered a planet.
>
> **The 13 Jupiter-mass cutoff is a rule of thumb rather than something of precise physical significance**. Larger objects will burn most of their deuterium and smaller ones will burn only a little, and the 13 Jupiter mass value is somewhere in between. The amount of deuterium burnt also depends to some extent on the composition of the object, specifically on the amount of helium and deuterium present and on the fraction of heavier elements, which determines the atmospheric opacity and thus the radiative cooling rate.

The smallest object that can be a star would be a little larger than Jupiter.

By comparison to other stars it would be quite literally cold.

See Wikipedia's webpage "[Brown Dwarf - Spectral class Y](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_dwarf#Spectral_class_Y)":

> "WISE data has revealed hundreds of new brown dwarfs. Of these, fourteen are classified as cool Ys. One of the Y dwarfs, called [WISE 1828+2650](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WISE_1828%2B2650), was, as of August 2011, the record holder for the coldest brown dwarf – emitting no visible light at all, this type of object resembles free-floating planets more than stars. **WISE 1828+2650 was initially estimated to have an atmospheric temperature cooler than 300 K — for comparison, the upper end of room temperature is 298 K (25 °C; 77 °F). Its temperature has since been revised and newer estimates put it in the range of 250 to 400 K (−23 to 127 °C; −10 to 260 °F)**.
>
> In April 2014, [WISE 0855−0714](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WISE_0855%E2%88%920714) was announced with a temperature profile estimated around 225 to 260 K (−48 to −13 °C; −55 to 8 °F) and a mass of 3 to 10 MJ. It was also unusual in that its observed parallax meant a distance close to 7.2±0.7 light years from the Solar System.

[image: Comparison of star sizes - Compared with Earth's Sun and Jupiter]

See also: "[The Coldest Brown Dwarf (Or Free Floating Planet)?: The Y Dwarf WISE 1828+2650](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.1669)" (Jan 8 2013), by Charles A. Beichman, Christopher R. Gelino, J. Davy Kirkpatrick, Travis S. Barman, Kenneth A. Marsh, Michael C. Cushing, and E.L. Wright:

> "... suggests a mass in the range 0.5-20 MJup for ages of 0.1-10 Gyr with an effective temperature in the range 250-400 K. The broad range in mass is due primarily to the unknown age of the object.".

Comment: I think this depends on what you mean by the 'size' of a star: white dwarfs can be pretty small, but they're obviously a lot more massive than the Moon.  I think most plausible white dwarfs are also much too hot.

Comment: The are other *candidates* but there are associated problems fitting them into an answer to the question. Take for example a [neutron star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_star#Formation): "... all nuclear fuel in the core has been exhausted," and "... most of the light generated by a neutron star is in X-rays.". For a [white dwarf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_dwarf): "The material in a white dwarf no longer undergoes fusion reactions, so the star has no source of energy. As a result, it cannot support itself by the heat generated by fusion against gravitational collapse, ...".

Comment: I agree that neutron stars are not good candidates.  White dwarfs are a bit less insane: although they have no source of fuel they take a *very* long time to cool down: I think such a thing can sit for more than a billion years at a life-friendly temperature.  I'm going to add a note on this to my answer (the orbital mechanics make it clear it would not work).